# how to deal with superSubset()

Tags: r, error-handling, analysis

I have this dataset

```
dput(head(df1, 10))
structure(list(ID = 1:10, V = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0), Puk = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Tall = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), Sit = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), STS = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tlf = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1), score = c(0.99, 0.99, 1, 0.99, 0.33, 0.67, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 
0.33)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

where I am trying to perform the qualitative comparative analysis. I have run the following function for the necessity analysis.

```
package(QCA)
superSubset(df1,outcome="score", 
            conditions="V,Puk,Sit,Tall, STS,tlf", relation = "necessity", 
            incl.cut=0.9, cov.cut=0.6,ron.cut = 0.6)
```

but I am obtaining this error:

```
Error in superSubset(df1, outcome = "score", conditions = "V,Puk,Sit,Tall, STS,tlf",  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out which problem is going on. Wouòd you have any tips with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those instances when your `tibble` needs to be a `data.frame`.

```r
library(QCA)

superSubset(as.data.frame(df1),outcome="score", relation = "necessity", 
             incl.cut=0.9, cov.cut=0.6, ron.cut = 0.2)
                                    inclN   RoN   covN  
------------------------------------------------------- 
 1  ID[3] + tlf[0]                  0.948  0.248  0.662 
 2  V[0] + Puk[1]                   0.948  0.248  0.662 
 3  V[1] + tlf[0]                   0.948  0.248  0.662 
 4  Puk[0] + Tall[1]                0.948  0.248  0.662 
 5  Puk[1] + Sit[0]                 0.948  0.248  0.662 
 6  Tall[1] + Sit[0]                0.948  0.248  0.662 
 7  Tall[1] + tlf[0]                0.948  0.248  0.662 
 8  Sit[0] + STS[1]                 0.948  0.248  0.662 
 9  Sit[1] + tlf[0]                 0.948  0.248  0.662 
10  STS[1] + tlf[0]                 0.948  0.248  0.662 
11  ID[1] + V[1] + Puk[0]           0.948  0.248  0.662 
12  ID[1] + V[1] + Tall[0]          0.948  0.248  0.662 
13  ID[1] + V[1] + Sit[0]           0.948  0.248  0.662 
14  ID[6] + V[0] + STS[1]           0.948  0.248  0.662 
15  ID[5] + Puk[1] + Tall[0]        0.948  0.248  0.662 
16  ID[7] + Puk[1] + Tall[1]        0.948  0.248  0.662 
17  ID[8] + Puk[1] + Tall[0]        0.948  0.248  0.662 
18  ID[9] + Puk[1] + Tall[1]        0.948  0.248  0.662 
19  ID[6] + Puk[0] + STS[1]         0.948  0.248  0.662 
20  ID[7] + Tall[1] + Sit[1]        0.948  0.248  0.662 
21  ID[10] + Tall[1] + Sit[1]       0.948  0.248  0.662 
22  ID[7] + Tall[1] + tlf[1]        0.948  0.248  0.662 
23  ID[9] + Tall[1] + tlf[1]        0.948  0.248  0.662 
24  ID[1] + Sit[0] + tlf[1]         0.948  0.248  0.662 
25  V[1] + Puk[1] + Tall[0]         0.948  0.248  0.662 
26  V[1] + Puk[0] + Sit[1]          0.948  0.248  0.662 
27  V[1] + Puk[0] + STS[1]          0.948  0.248  0.662 
28  V[1] + Tall[0] + Sit[1]         0.948  0.248  0.662 
29  V[1] + Tall[0] + STS[1]         0.948  0.248  0.662 
30  Puk[1] + Tall[1] + Sit[1]       0.948  0.248  0.662 
31  Tall[1] + Sit[1] + tlf[1]       0.948  0.248  0.662 
32  ID[5] + V[1] + Puk[1] + Sit[1]  0.948  0.248  0.662 
33  ID[7] + V[1] + Puk[1] + Sit[1]  0.948  0.248  0.662 
34  ID[5] + V[1] + Sit[1] + tlf[1]  0.948  0.248  0.662 
35  ID[7] + V[1] + Sit[1] + tlf[1]  0.948  0.248  0.662 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just in case, may I just ask if the value that you have enter in the last argument (0.2 in place of 0.6) is plausible for necessity analysis?

Comment: @alias no, it was just to get an output on the function to demonstrate that this was the correct syntax (the partial data set that you provided did not get an output at 0.6)